# Swift 4: Cannot convert value of type() to expected argument type

Tags: swift, xcode

I am VERY NEW to swift and can't seem to get passed this error:

> /Users/me/code/Apps/Aero-Eco/Aero-Eco/Controller/ViewController.swift:36:109:
>   Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type
>   '((UIAlertAction) -> Void)?'

Here's the code triggering it

```
@IBAction func loginPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!) { (user, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error!)

                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Those credentials are not recognized.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: self.clearLogin()))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            } else {
                print("Log in successful!")
                self.clearLogin()
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToSwitchboard", sender: self)
            }
        }
    }

func clearLogin() {
        self.emailTextField.text! = ""
        self.passwordTextField.text! = ""
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:{(action) in self.clearLogin()}))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is why. You have to add `(action) in`

```
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK".localized, style: .default, handler: {

      (action) in//added this line 
self.clearLogin()
    })
```